# Error while compiling on sources in R on MacOS

Tags: r, xcode, macos

I am using R 4.0.1 on MacOS 10.15.10. I try to install mvtnorm() package. Unfortunately, I need the most current version. The binaries of mvtnorm() are build using R < 4. As such I need to install from source. Here is what I get

install.packages("mvtnorm")

There is a binary version available but the source version is later:
binary source needs_compilation
mvtnorm 1.1-0 1.1-1 TRUE

Do you want to install from sources the package which needs compilation? (Yes/no/cancel) y
installing the source package ‘mvtnorm’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/mvtnorm_1.1-1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 163902 bytes (160 KB)
downloaded 160 KB

installing source package ‘mvtnorm’ ...
** package ‘mvtnorm’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
/usr/local/Cellar/llvm/8.0.0_1/bin/clang -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -I/usr/local/include -fPIC -Wall -g -O2 -c C_FORTRAN_interface.c -o C_FORTRAN_interface.o
In file included from C_FORTRAN_interface.c:8:
In file included from ./mvtnorm.h:2:
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include/R.h:55:11: fatal error: 'stdlib.h' file not found
include  /* Not used by R itself, but widely assumed in packages */
      ^~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make: *** [C_FORTRAN_interface.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘mvtnorm’

removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/mvtnorm’
restoring previous ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/mvtnorm’
Warning in install.packages :
installation of package ‘mvtnorm’ had non-zero exit status
The downloaded source packages are in
‘/private/var/folders/py/z1sgc8b17l5fp8pmrpnrjykm0000gn/T/Rtmpdrwvh2/downloaded_packages’

I already have the latest Xcode:
Profs-MacBook-Pro: xcode-select --install

xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates

Profs-MacBook-Pro: softwareupdate --install -a

Software Update Tool

Finding available software

No updates are available.

Any suggestion is welcome!
Best
Sven

Comment: Hi, let me recommend the  mailing list  `r-sig-mac@r-project.org`   There are searchable archives & ever since teh release of `R 4.X` there's been a ton of chatter about building and compiling packages.  You may have to register at r-project.org to get on the mailing list.

Comment: Thank Carl. I'll check it out. Best, Sven